# TypeORM: Read Only Connection (Oracle)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, orm, typeorm

I'm using [TypeORM](http://typeorm.io) and I was wonderring if there's a way to prevent any edit to the database. I'm not totally sure if my entities will create or edit columns or tables in the database and I don't want that to happen like when setting relations between the tables, I don't want TypeORM to create a new foreign key if it does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could create a DDL trigger that raises an exception.

```
create or replace trigger prevent_ddl_trg 
before ddl on schema
declare
begin
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'DDL not allowed')
end;
```

In 11.2 and higher, this seems to allow alters and drops on the trigger itself.

You can disable with:

```
alter trigger prevent_ddl_trg disable;
```

And enable with:

```
alter trigger prevent_ddl_trg enable;
```

Be careful with that though, you may prevent things you weren't expecting, like the ability to reset your own password.